# Any rest api of istio is available?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, microservices, istio, envoyproxy

Is there any rest API for Istio available?

If we want to work with istio through rest call, what options we have?
I'm new to istio.So help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kubernetes [API groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups) for Istio [CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/)

For example the `apiVersion:` `networking.istio.io/v1alpha3` can be accessed at `/apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3`.

`GET /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/gateways` will get gateways for all namespaces.

The full list of istio APIs can be found on istio [github](https://github.com/istio/api) page.

---

To directly access the kubernetes REST API follow [these](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api) instructions.

Hope this helps.